# How do I nest a drawer navigator inside a page that exists inside a Stack?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I want to create a small react native app with just a few screens: Login and Home.
However, I would also like to have a drawer navigator attached to the Home screen. The drawer will contain 3 additional screens:  Device Registration, Call, and Sound Check.  So far my App.js file looks like this

```
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Login from './src/components/Login';
import SignUp from './src/components/SignUp';
import DeviceRegistration from './src/components/DeviceRegistration';
import Call from './src/components/Call';
import Sound from './src/components/Sound';



export const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  SignUp: { screen: SignUp },
  DeviceRegistration: { screen: DeviceRegistration },
  Call: { screen: Call },
  Sound: { screen: Sound },
}, 
    {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Login'
    } 

);


export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    DeviceRegistration: { screen: DeviceRegistration },
    Call: { screen: Call },
    Sound: { screen: Sound },
}, {


});

export default Navigation;
```

Where do I put the Drawer inside of the Home screen so that I can create a hamburger icon which I can press to access the drawer navigation?

Comment: Where is this `Home` screen and where do you want the hamburger icon? Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJqvP.png?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped.  Home screen should be Signup.  I would like the Hamburger icon to appear on the Signup

Answer (score 0):

```
export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    SignUp: { screen: SignUp },
    DeviceRegistration: { screen: DeviceRegistration },
    Call: { screen: Call },
    Sound: { screen: Sound },
});

export const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Home: { screen: Drawer },
});
```

Then in your `Signup` component, call `this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')` to open the drawer.